# Phrases used in ending conversations

Tags: expressions, usage, oral, salutations

Which phrases are typically used when ending conversations? I know that *au revoir* and *à bientôt* are normally used, but surely that are many more phrases that can be used to end a conversation, so I would like to know which other such phrases can be used, as well as exactly in which context(s) can these phrases be used.

Comment: I was telling someone on the chat about *à plus* [on the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16298371#16298371) the other day. Very informal.

Comment: The differences between *Au revoir* and *à bientôt* have already been discussed [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/9723/358), maybe you'll want to rephrase question so that we can answer on the second part of it?

Comment: _A+_ definitely used frequently in electronic media (email or chat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a few rather informal alternatives: *à plus, à la prochaine, à la revoyure, tchao, tchuss*… The first two are closer to *à bientôt* (i.e. suggest that you are likely to see the person again soon), whereas the other are closer to *au revoir* (which just means “bye” despite what a literal translation might suggest). If you have a specific plan it's also possible to end a conversation with something like *à lundi*.

Finally, *bonne journée* (ou *bonne soirée*, *bon après-midi*, *bonne continuation*, *bonne route*, etc.) is also common, often together with *au revoir* or *à bientôt* (and not necessarily as a replacement).